# error in $ failed reading not a valid json value when i try to send requests via python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

so ive been trying to figure out how to do the 'follow' thing using python codes on imvu.com, but it always returns the message "invalid arguments" error in $: failed reading: not a valid json value"

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Origin": "https://secure.imvu.com/",
    "Referer": "https://secure.imvu.com/next/av/Sammy165/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36",
    "X-IMVU-SAUCE": "" #removed sauce for account safety
}
url = "https://api.imvu.com/profile/profile-user-696969696/subscriptions"
data = {"id": "https://api.imvu.com/profile/profile-user-175389029"}
req = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(req.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried
`requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)`
?

Comment: Either this or use `Content-Type: application/json` in your header. Specifying `json`  instead of `data` automatically does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do json.dumps(data). See code below

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
 "Origin": "https://secure.imvu.com/",
 "Referer": "https://secure.imvu.com/next/av/Sammy165/",
 "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36",
 "X-IMVU-SAUCE": "" #removed sauce for account safety
}
url = "https://api.imvu.com/profile/profile-user-696969696/subscriptions"
data = {"id": "https://api.imvu.com/profile/profile-user-175389029"}
req = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
print(req.text)
```

Output:

```
{"status":"failure","error":"ERROR-GENERIC-001","message":"Permission Denied: You are not allowed to modify this subscription set."}
```